# Javascript | Other way to do a for loop which is possible to break after success?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am trying to do a for loop to get all bots, but if I use a for loop I can't cancel the loop after I got success because I am using callback. Is there a other way to do the for loop so I could cancel it after I got the successful answer. I tried `return true`, `break`, `return` either of those didn't work.

```
    var myMessages = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){
        if ( bots[i].getInventory().getItems().length < capacity ){  
            var executed = false;
            bots[i].createDeposit({
                steamid: req.query.steamid,
                token: req.query.token,
                itemsFromThem: uniqueItems,
                message: req.query.message,
                callback: function( err, dbTradeId ){
                    if ( !executed ){
                        executed = true;
                        if ( !err && dbTradeId ){
                            res.json({ result: 1, dbTradeId: dbTradeId });
                        } else {
                            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but',err);
                            myMessages.push("Problem");
                            res.json({ error: err });                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found(2)');
            myMessages.push("Available bot not found(2)");
        }
    }
    } else {
        console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found');
        myMessages.push("Available bot not found"); 
    }
} catch(e){
    return res.json({ error: e.message, stack: e.stack });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify( myMessages));
```

Comment: You should write your callback function externally, and then call it rather than write it directly in the callback.

Comment: You can't as ``for`` is sync and ``createDeposit`` async

Comment: Sounds to me like this is a case for ES6 Generator Iterators. Generators can be thought of as functions that you can pause/stop/resume, and Generator Iterators are basically the same concept but with loops. If it emits done: true, (which you can do whenever you want), it's done, regardless of whether or not it completed iterating the set. I highly recommend you look 'em up.

Comment: You need to put your for inside a generator. If you need it in client side app, make sure you use babel too.
http://voidcanvas.com/synchronous-ajax-with-es6-generators/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the loop will do all iterations before the first callback is called, thus you can not cancel it. How about specifying functions to handle success and failure when its done?

```
var length = bots.length,
    iterator = 0;

checkBot(bots[iterator], done, fail);

function checkBot(bot, done, fail) {
    if ( bot.getInventory().getItems().length < capacity ){
        var executed = false;
        bot.screateDeposit({
            steamid: req.query.steamid,
            token: req.query.token,
            itemsFromThem: uniqueItems,
            message: req.query.message,
            callback: function( err, dbTradeId ){
                if ( !executed ){
                    executed = true;
                    if ( !err && dbTradeId ){
                        done(dbTradeId);
                    } else {
                        fail(err);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function done(dbTradeId) {
    // Dont continue after success? 
    res.json({ result: 1, dbTradeId: dbTradeId });
}

function fail(err) {

    // res.json({ error: err });

    // Check next bot?
    if(iterator++ < length){
        checkBot(bots[iterator], done, fail);
    }
}
```